# Problem in printing Russian characters in rendering .docx in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, encoding, r-markdown, rendering, .doc

I am trying to render a .docx file using Rmarkdown that includes Russian characters in the dataframe

````
---
params: 
title: "Encoding Issue"
output:
 bookdown::word_document2:
   reference_docx: Word_template.docx
classoption: a4paper
always_allow_html: yes
lang: ru
---

```{r data}
df <- data.frame(x = 
c("Не хватка медикаментов",
"Далеко ехать",
"Опасность на дорогах к мед.учереждению",
"Only one family physician")
)
Encoding(df$x) <- "UTF-8"
```

```{r cat}
cat(df$x)
```
````

> �� ������ ������������ ������ ����� ��������� �� ������� � ���.����������� Only one family physician

````
```{r print}
print(df$x)
```
````

> [1] "\xcd\xe5 \xf5\xe2\xe0\xf2\xea\xe0 \xec\xe5\xe4\xe8\xea\xe0\xec\xe5\xed\xf2\xee\xe2"
> [2] "\xc4\xe0\xeb\xe5\xea\xee \xe5\xf5\xe0\xf2\xfc"
> [3] "\xce\xef\xe0\xf1\xed\xee\xf1\xf2\xfc \xed\xe0 \xe4\xee\xf0\xee\xe3\xe0\xf5 \xea \xec\xe5\xe4.\xf3\xf7\xe5\xf0\xe5\xe6\xe4\xe5\xed\xe8\xfe"
> [4] "Only one family physician"

The rendered .docx file shows the printed result as

> [1] "<U+041D><U+0435> <U+0445><U+0432><U+0430><U+0442><U+043A><U+0430> <U+043C><U+0435><U+0434><U+0438><U+043A><U+0430><U+043C><U+0435><U+043D><U+0442><U+043E><U+0432>"
> [2] "<U+0414><U+0430><U+043B><U+0435><U+043A><U+043E> <U+0435><U+0445><U+0430><U+0442><U+044C>"
> [3] "<U+041E><U+043F><U+0430><U+0441><U+043D><U+043E><U+0441><U+0442><U+044C> <U+043D><U+0430> <U+0434><U+043E><U+0440><U+043E><U+0433><U+0430><U+0445> <U+043A> <U+043C><U+0435><U+0434>.<U+0443><U+0447><U+0435><U+0440><U+0435><U+0436><U+0434><U+0435><U+043D><U+0438><U+044E>"
> [4] "Only one family physician"

The `Sys.getlocale()` is

> "LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251"

Where could be the origin of the encoding issue? Is there any way to correctly render the .docx file with the correct characters?

> Не хватка медикаментов Далеко ехать Опасность на дорогах к мед.учереждению Only one family physician

I have also tried with `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "English")`. The .docx template is set to "UTF-8". The rmarkdown is also set to `options(encoding = "UTF-8")`.

Comment: Does it render correctly if you use `cat` instead of `print`? I BTW recall experiencing a similar issue which happened only on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `enc2utf8` in this situation:

````
```{r data}
df <- data.frame(x = 
c("Нехватка медикаментов",
"Далеко ехать",
"Опасность на дорогах к мед.учреждению",
"Only one family physician")
)
```

```{r}
enc2utf8(df$x)
```
````